# Nginx+PHP-FPM "File not found" when changing Root directory in Centos 8

Tags: nginx, centos, php-fpm

I'm new to nginx, and I want to change the root directory path.

File: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
}
```

That works perfectly!

But if I change the root directory to:

```
    root         /home;
```

I get the error "File not found." in the browser.

Below is /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file content for additional info:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using? SELinux would definitely prevent you from setting the nginx root to `/home`. Post the full error message.

Comment: Using Centos 8 (Title updated)

/var/log/nginx/error.log

[error] 19845#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xx, server: _, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jordanm I changed SELinux to `permissive` as follow, it resolved the problem.

```
Setenforce Permissive
```